# Converting preg_replace to preg_replace_callback for php 5.6

Tags: php, preg-replace

Edited to include preg_replace_callback I have tried

I've just upgraded to php 5.6 and my preg_replace code is not working.  I have tried to follow previous examples but cannot get it working.  The code below should take a parapgraph in $newDescription and replace any email addresses found with the text "[Email Removed]".

My old code :

```
$newDescription = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)/','[email removed]',$newDescription);
```

My new code attempt is below  but it is not returning anything :

```
$newDescription = preg_replace_callback('/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)/', function($match) {return "[email removed]"; }, $newDescription);
```

Comment: Why  do you need `preg_replace_callback`? You do not need it. The former should work.

Comment: Well, I don't see `preg_replace_callback` being used anywhere. You are using `preg_replace` in both attempts. Use it and it will work fine. [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6b858cc792860c4d0fb84ec1d0bd3f7935790b9)

Comment: Sorry, i meant  $newDescription = preg_replace_callback('/\+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{9,20}[0-9]/', function($match) {return "[email removed]"; }, $newDescription);

Comment: As it has already been said you don't need to use `preg_replace_callback()`. So I don't see what your problem is. If your code isn't working as expected please read [mcve].

Comment: It was working fine until I upgraded to php 5.6 and now it gives the error Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 16.  The code was preg_replace('/\+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{9,20}[0-9]/', '[telephone removed]', $trimmed['description']);